# Fix touchpad that is responding "sideways" (Windows 10)

Tags: windows-10, laptop, touchpad

One of our family laptops (an HP Pavilion x360 running Windows 10) has a weird problem - the touchpad responds "sideways". In other words: If I move my finger across it from left to right, the cursor moves up, when I move from the bottom of the pad to the top (in other words "up"), the cursor moves to the left, and so forth.

Looking in Settings | Devices | Mouse & touchpad, I see nothing to adjust this - the only touchpad setting shown is for the delay. Going into Additional mouse options brings up a window that includes a Hardware tab and an Elan tab (apparently the manufacturer is Elan). Disabling and Enabling did not change the behavior. The device driver is from 2015, but the touchpad worked normally until relatively recently. Going deeper into the Elan tab didn't find anything either

Unfortunately, I've not found anything helpful via web searches.

Any suggestions how to fix this?

Comment: you sure its Elan, Most if not all hp uses synaptics. Use this driver : http://ftp.hp.com/pub/softpaq/sp81501-82000/sp81891.exe. But before, uninstall your current one and use that one.

Comment: @LateGameReviewer: Why would it show Elan in the setting if it was Synaptics?

Comment: Because when you check the drivers page on HP it shows only synaptics. if theres a model that goes for Elan, it would be listed but its not. Thats the reason. Wrong drivers will mess the functionality of your device.